# Can a component method which modifies its navigation prop be unit tested?

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I need to figure out how to test a component method that doesn't return a value and doesn't change any of the states of its component, all it does is push another screen.

I'm using jest and enzyme to access a class methods and states.

This is the method I want to test (if possible):

```
  signUp() {
    this.props.navigation.push('Signup');
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, just pass in a mock for the `navigation` prop:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

class SimpleComponent extends React.Component {
  signUp() {
    this.props.navigation.push('Signup');
  }
  render() { return null; }
}

test('signUp', () => {
  const navigationMock = { push: jest.fn() };
  const wrapper = shallow(<SimpleComponent navigation={navigationMock}/>);
  wrapper.instance().signUp();
  expect(navigationMock.push).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Signup');  // Success!
});
```